# Using HTTPS search in iGoogle search bar?

Tags: google-search, igoogle, https

Is it possible to set the iGoogle search bar to search https://www.google.com rather than the HTTP version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, Google's SSL search is still in Beta, and is limited to only search from its SSL beta page via https://google.com and https://encrypted.google.com.
Even Google image search is not currently supported.